# RSpec controller error: database getting populated on its own

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

Thanks in advance for whoever tries to help. My development db is empty but still on testing it is populating db by 29 authors where it should be only two, please help if I'm going wrong

*(spec/controllers/authors_controller.rb)*

```
it "loads all of the authors into @authors" do
  auth1, auth2 = Fabricate(:author), Fabricate(:author)
  get :index

  expect(assigns(:authors)).to match_array([auth1, auth2])
end
```

*(app/controllers/authors_controller.rb)*

```
def index
  @authors = Author.all
end
```

**error**

```
AuthorsController GET #index loads all of the authors into @authors
     Failure/Error: expect(assigns(:authors)).to match_array([auth1, auth2])
       expected collection contained:  [#<Author id: 28, first_name: "Kellen", last_name: "Bosco", created_at: "2015-11-10 06:11:45", updated_at: "2015-11-10 06:11:45">, #<Author id: 29, first_name: "Axel", last_name: "Reinger", created_at: "2015-11-10 06:11:45", updated_at: "2015-11-10 06:11:45">]
       actual collection contained:  

  [Authors  from id: "1" to "29"]
```

Comment: you might not be emptying out your database between test suite runs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @sevenseacat pointed out, you're not cleaning your database between specs. [DatabaseCleaner](https://github.com/DatabaseCleaner/database_cleaner) gem will do that for you. After installing, be sure to place the following in your `spec_helper`:

```
RSpec.configure do |config|

  config.before(:suite) do
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :transaction
    DatabaseCleaner.clean_with(:truncation)
  end

  config.around(:each) do |example|
    DatabaseCleaner.cleaning do
      example.run
    end
  end

end
```